# what could cause a scraping noise after tire rotation

Tags: tires, wheels, noise

After having one tire replaced, and the tires rotated, drove out of the shop immediately to a grrr (rubbing/grinding) sound momentarily, once per tire rotation.  I noticed the "back" tires have pretty low clearance to their encasing, perhaps there's something wrong there? (the front ones are kind of worn on the inside rim, as well, maybe its just a "normal wear" pattern issue)?  It sounds as if the tread is being worn away but if I get above like 30 it sounds like my tires going to disintegrate ;|

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After taking it back to the shop, the tech. diagnosed it as "the new back tire inside rim wheel weights are rubbing" (apparently they didn't rub when those tires were in the front).  So rebalance the rear wheels (i.e. new wheel weights) and I'm back in business.

Update: got this again at a different date, even after doing a balancing.  I just told the guy about it and he "did something" (bent them in more) and it works.  Guess there's not a lot of clearance in my vehicle (Accord) for rear inside wheel weights...

Comment: Rubbing to what, exactly?

Comment: Was the tire shop happy with the wear that you could see?

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing I'm not sure though there wasn't a lot of clearance between the tire and the inside of the vehicle and I assume that's what was rubbing (the wheel weight against something).  It sure sounded like it was rubber hitting the frame though (like when you have a bicycle with its tire out of alignment) but guess it was just the wheel weights.  Also sounded like if I were to hit 60 my tire would explode (got louder with higher rpm's)

Comment: We have had tape type weights rub on the brake calipers. Especially if they are stacked in layers. Easy to fix.